# Convert array of objects to array of specific property from each object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using felixge/node-mysql to run this query:
"SELECT DISTINCT tablename.id FROM tablename"

The rows returned are (obviously) in this format:
[{id: 123},{id: 234},{id: 345}]

I can't figure out how to get this:
[123, 234, 345]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for --- it must be the first thing you learn before you write any program in js. Also relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Thanks for the tip @zerkms, I was just looking for a shorter way than looping and extracting myself.

Comment: you should have stated that explicitly, we obviously cannot read your minds. "I can't figure out" doesn't correlate with what you've just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ES5, such is rather easy using a [map transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

For example:

```
var arr = [{id: 123},{id: 234},{id: 345}];
var res = arr.map(function (o) {
   return o.id;
});
```

Doing this "manually" with a loop would look like so:

```
var arr = [{id: 123},{id: 234},{id: 345}];
var res = [];
// Loop over the array
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var item = arr[i];
  // And add new value we want to result array
  res.push(item.id);
}
```

(Note that the variables are function-scoped, but I prefer to use "close placement" of `var`.)

Comment: Upvoted because correct, but OP still won't become a better developer from this answer. Would be amazing if an alternative with explicit loop and array `.push()` was added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lodash](https://www.npmjs.org/package/lodash) or [underscore](https://www.npmjs.org/package/underscore):

```
var _ = require('lodash'); // or 'underscore'

var a = [{id: 123},{id: 234},{id: 345}];

var b = _.pluck(a, 'id');

console.log(b); // [123, 234, 345]
```

Comment: Just a `.map()` would be enough without requiring OP to bring a whole library for a trivial task.